# Ajax call using url from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, npm

I am using an API that only allows you to call specific entries, each with their own unique url.

To automate the calling of the entries I require, I created a variable using a template in a for loop that results in a string built from array data.

console.loging the variable in the loop outputs the expected urls to the console.

When I tried to use the variable in the ajax call, it was treating the url as originating from my npm server and prepending my server url to the request.

On looking through some StackOverflow entries I learned that a scheme must be used to tell the ajax call that the url originates from outside my npm server.

I modified the variable to start after the ".com/" and the ajax request to concatenate the main url and the specific page following the ".com/"

This resulted in a url that appended a "%22" appended between the main url and the specific page data represented by the variable.

Is there any way to call this variable in a for loop to do what I am attempting?

Code is below with my private key redacted.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Additional Info:

The first snippet of code is a script which allows me to create an array of objects from a csv file which contains, among other data, the movie title and year released. It is this data that is being fed into the variable template with "+"'s between the title words so that it matches the url requirements.

ex.

{Title: Gone with the Wind, Year: 1939}

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Gone+with+the+Wind&y=1939&apikey=########

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Javascript

```
const moviesCSV = [ ]
const movies =[ ]

d3.csv("./data/movieQuotes.csv", function (data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        moviesCSV.push(data[i]);
    }
});

setTimeout(() => {

for (let i = 0; i < moviesCSV.length; i++) {

    let query = `"?t=${moviesCSV[0].Title.replace(/ /g, "+")}&y=${moviesCSV[0].Year}&apikey=########"`;

    $.ajax({
              url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/" + query,
              dataType: "JSON",
              type: "GET",
              success: (res) => {
                console.log(res)
              },
              error: (err) => {
                console.log(err)
              }
        })

}}, 3000)
```

Comment: Why are there double-quotes in your `query` string? Also, I highly recommend using the `data` object property for constructing query parameters

Comment: You are always using the first element of your `moviesCSV` array when you do this: `moviesCSV[0]`.

Comment: you're putting the `"` in yourself ... see after the first  ` and before the last ` in your let query line? remove the first and last `"` ... that line should be ... `let query = \`?t=${moviesCSV[0].Title.replace(/ /g, "+")}&y=${moviesCSV[0].Year}&apikey=########\`;` ... modern javascript has effectively 3 quote characters, `"`, `'` and `\`` ... the last is (as you know because you use it) more powerful - by putting `"` inside `\`` means you are adding `"` to the resulting string

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. The double quotes were an artifact from when I was using the template to express the entire URL as I assumed the quotes were a required part of the url value and so I was ensuring their presence. Thank you everyone!